# Displaying data from multiple tables in a gridview

Tags: asp.net, sql, gridview

Hello I have some code that displays data from a datasource in a gridview. It is supposed to take columns from two different tables, however the page never loads (tested on localhost and also VS debug). When debugging I tested my query in excel and it executes fine. TODBC I'm using is ProvideX. Both tables display properly individually. Code is below, any questions let me know.

ASP

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AllowPaging="True" 
    AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="CUST_NO" HeaderText="CUST_NO" 
             SortExpression="CUST_NO" />
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>

<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
    ConnectionString="Dsn=Jake" ProviderName="System.Data.Odbc" 
    SelectCommand="SELECT CWIPH.CUST_NO, CJCMS.JOB_DESC FROM { OJ CWIPH CWIPH
    INNER JOIN CJCMS CJCMS ON CWIPH.JOB_NO = CJCMS.JOB_NO }">
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Comment: Is there anything in your Page_Load? Can you modify your search to not use implicit joins? I don't think that will solve your problem, but it would make it easier for us to understand and implicit joins are very, very outdated syntax

Comment: Ok query changed, edited above still the same issue though.

Comment: And no there is nothing in my page load. Above is the only code in my project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to change your SelectCommand to:

```
SELECT * from CWIPH INNER JOIN CJCMS ON CWIPH.JOB_NO=CJCMS.JOB_NO
```

Comment: I edited my code above to my current query. The page is still not loading.

Comment: I added a Where at the end to look for a specific cust_no and the results loaded. Maybe there are just too many results. Thanks for the help